# PowerShell sql deployment script - handle new subfolders

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a PowerShell question relating to the script below.  The script finds all the instances of "update.sql" and provides the user with the choice to run them by entering "Y" or "N".  Up until today this has worked well.  However, due to a change in the folder structure additional folders containing their own versions of "update.sql" have been introduced.  When the script runs it also finds these instances of "update.sql" and the user has to enter "N" several times.  Not the end of the world but I would rather they didn't have to.

When the code reaches select "-First 1" the selected folder is ie:
\Pro\TFS Builds\Ni - ProjName - Databases\Ni - ProjName - Databases_20131113.1

Inside this folder are 5 additional folders named:

ProjName Release 1

Buff Release 1

Logs

Por Release 1

Por Release 2

All these folders with exception of Logs have 3 subfolders named:

CompanyName_Pro2000_Audit_LIVE

CompanyName_Pro2000_Control_LIVE

CompanyName_Pro2000_LIVE

These are the folders where "update.sql" resides.

I need the code to find \Pro\TFS Builds\Ni - ProjName - Databases\Ni - ProjName - Databases_20131113.1 and then select the folder within it entitled ProjName Release 1.  Thereafter each folder within ProjName Release 1 with "update.sql" would be identified to the user for a choice of executing the script.  Any help amending the current code to do this would be great.

Jak

Current Script:

```
    #Locate all update.sql related to the project
    #$dbscript = ls '\\Pro\TFSBuilds\'$TFSName'\Databases\' | sort name -Descending | select -First 1

    $dbscripts = ls '\\Pro\TFS Builds\' | ? {$_.Name -like 'Ni - '+$TFSName+'*- Databases*'}
    $dbscript = ls $dbscripts.FullName | sort Name -Descending |  select -First 1
    $updatescripts = ls $dbscript.FullName update.sql -Recurse

    foreach($script in $updatescripts)
    {
    Write-Host $script.Name "found....`n `n"
    #Write-Host $script.FullName.Substring(36,$script.FullName.Length - 36) "


        #$scriptin = Read-Host "Run Script.....`n `n" $script.FullName  "on" $sqlserver
        $scriptin = Read-Host $script.FullName.Substring(25,$script.FullName.Length - 25) "on" $sqlserver "`n `n""Do you want to run Database Script: (Enter Y or N)"
        if($scriptin -ieq "Y")
        {
            try
            {

                $returnres = invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $script.FullName -serverinstance $sqlserver -Username '********' -Password '**********' -Database 'CompanyName_Pro2000_LIVE'
                Write-Host "Script complete.....`n `n"
            }
            catch
            {
            Write-Host "Script not run.....`n `n"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dbscripts = ls '\\Pro\TFS Builds\' | ? {$_.Name -like 'Ni - '+$TFSName+'*- Databases*'}
$dbscript = ls $dbscripts.FullName | sort Name -Descending | select -First 1
$updatescripts = ls $dbscript.FullName update.sql -Recurse
foreach ($script in $updatescripts) {
    $resp = Read-Host "Run script from $($script.Directory.Name) on $sqlserver`n `nDo you want to run Database Script: (Enter Y or N)"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith.  Looking at my post I realise it looks like Databases_20131113.1 will be a constant.  Sorry, it won't.  There will be a large number of folders named Databases_20131113.1 or Databases_20131113.2 or Databases_20131114.1. The original code sorts these folders in order to identify the latest.  Once this folder is identified then a subfolder within it entitled ProjName Release 1 that has 3 subfolders Audit_Live, Control_Live and Live all contain update.sql scripts that need to be run.  Any additional help would be appreciated. Jak

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Keith, greatly appreciated.  problem sorted.  Many thanks.  Jak